# Unable to do Ajax request in Laravel/Vue.Js

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, vue.js, csrf

So I've gotten to the point where I'm starting to bang my head against the wall with this issue, I have tried googling for a solution but all pages simply say "Include the CSRF token", which I have included.

The route is using the default 'web' middleware.

[CSRF Token included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksGB8.png)

I'm at my wits end here, so any guidance is highly appreciated.

Using the latest Laravel 5.7, all components are up to date

JS Script:

```
<script>
export default {
    name: "BankIdLogin",
    data() {
        return {
            status: '',
            error: '',
            message: '',
        }
    },

    created() {

    },

    methods: {
        initiateBankID: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            axios
                .post(
                    "/login/bankIdAuthentication", {
                        _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                        ssn: $('#ssn').val()
                    }
                )
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(res => console.log(res));
        },
        collectBankID() {

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Response from the call:

```
{
   "message":"",
   "exception":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
   "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
   "line":204,
   "trace":[
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
     "line":176,
     "function":"prepareException",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/app/Exceptions/Handler.php",
     "line":51,
     "function":"render",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
     "line":83,
     "function":"render",
     "class":"App\\Exceptions\\Handler",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
     "line":55,
     "function":"handleException",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php",
     "line":49,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
     "line":151,
     "function":"handle",
     "class":"Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
     "line":53,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php",
     "line":63,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
     "line":151,
     "function":"handle",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
     "line":53,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
     "line":37,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
     "line":151,
     "function":"handle",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
     "line":53,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php",
     "line":66,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
     "line":151,
     "function":"handle",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
     "line":53,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
     "line":104,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
     "line":681,
     "function":"then",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
     "line":656,
     "function":"runRouteWithinStack",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
     "line":622,
     "function":"runRoute",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
     "line":611,
     "function":"dispatchToRoute",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
     "line":176,
     "function":"dispatch",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
     "line":30,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php",
     "line":65,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
     "line":151,
     "function":"handle",
     "class":"Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
     "line":53,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
     "line":57,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
     "line":151,
     "function":"handle",
     "class":"Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
     "line":53,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
     "line":31,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
     "line":151,
     "function":"handle",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
     "line":53,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
     "line":31,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
     "line":151,
     "function":"handle",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
     "line":53,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
     "line":27,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
     "line":151,
     "function":"handle",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
     "line":53,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
     "line":62,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
     "line":151,
     "function":"handle",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
     "line":53,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
     "line":104,
     "function":"Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
     "line":151,
     "function":"then",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
     "line":116,
     "function":"sendRequestThroughRouter",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
     "type":"->"
  },
  {
     "file":"/var/www/html/public/index.php",
     "line":54,
     "function":"handle",
     "class":"Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
     "type":"->"
  }
   ]
}
```

web.php

```
Route::post('/login/bankIdAuthentication', 'Api\LoginController@bankidAuthentication');
```

BankIDController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\BankidSignature;
use App\Models\User;
use Frozzare\Personnummer\Personnummer;
use ILabs\Api\BankId;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends BaseController
{
public function bankidAuthentication(Request $request)
{
    $ssn = Personnummer::format($request->post('ssn'), TRUE) ?? $request->post('ssn');
    if ($ssn === '')
        $ssn = $request->post('ssn');

    if ($ssn !== '') {
        $user = User::where(
            [
                'ssn'    => $ssn,
                'active' => 1,
            ]
        );
        if (!$user->count()) {
            return \GuzzleHttp\json_encode(['status' => 0, 'message' => __('INVALID_SSN')]);
        }

        $bankid = new BankId();

        try {
            $bankid->bankIDAuthenticationRequest($ssn);

            session(['ssn' => $ssn]);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return \GuzzleHttp\json_encode(['status' => 0, 'message' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
    return \GuzzleHttp\json_encode(['status' => 0, 'message' => 'Unknown Error']);
}
}
```

**EDIT**
Disabling CSRF in the web middleware makes the route work properly, so it's somehow CSRF related after all...

It seems that the _token supplied by the function doesnt match the _token in the session (Dont know if they are supposed to match or if they are related to each other in another way) Example:

```
_token from request: wiqBYqBdtMJL9JxInySSSBGtYzPGHAjePLNBILRz
_token in session: e5caPLy6N82QEQoUzixHAvojE2SortRKqxOFM3sI
```

[Request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTi15.png)

**EDIT 2**
After some more research I've come to realize that my issue is that the Ajax calls seem to start their own new session.. much like described here [Laracast - _token doesnt match session _token](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/csrf-form-token-doesnt-match-session-token?page=1)

I have however not been able to make it work with any of the "Fixes" they supplied in that thread.

**EDIT 3**

I dont know whats going on anymore, i did a commit of my changes and now its working..

Comment: What is your Laravel route ?

Comment: @IjasAmeenudeen added the route to the question

Comment: I can't see missing CSRF anywhere in the exception stack, can you show the controller method or any custom middleware you are using here?

Comment: That was just a guess, since thats the only results i get when trying to google for the exception

Comment: Did you try to set the accept and content type headers to your axios request?. Also please paste the controller method that you are calling

Comment: Does your js console on the browser shows you any error?

Comment: No error in the console. ive added the controller to the question

Comment: @JacoboTapia no i havent, ill try doing that

Comment: I usually get the input from the request with `$request->input(“theValue”)`. Don’t know if that could be something

Comment: The problem is that it never gets that far, i have a breakpoint at the start of the function that it never reaches

Comment: Are you sure that the route in your request reaches your controller? I mean why don’t you try `my-app-url/login/bankIdAuthentication` the full url

Comment: Setting Content-Type and Accept headers changed nothing

Comment: Changing the route from a POST to a GET works, but this isnt really data that i want to send with a GET

Comment: Try use the full url to that route.

Comment: Using full URL doesnt change anything

Comment: Can you post the request header as well ?\

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTi15.png

Comment: @IjasAmeenudeen Forgot to mention you

Comment: Try moving your route into `routes/api.php`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Html page from where you are calling this ajax add this

```
var bankIdAuthenticationRoute = "{{route('bankIdAuthenticationRoute')}}"
var csrf = "{{csrf_token()}}"
```

And then use both variable in your JS file for that Ajax call.

Comment: Neither the route nor the CSRF is wrong, ive tried with full URL and the csrf is included in the request